# Duck typing for indexed iteratables in Powershell

Tags: powershell, duck-typing

Instead of piping over collections, it's sometimes more convenient to procedurally loop through them. And to avoid differentiating between `$_` and `$_.Key`/`$_.Value` depending on input, a more consistent key/value handling would be nice:

```
ForEach-KV $object { Param($k, $v); do-stuff }
```

However a common type probing has its drawbacks:

```
#-- iterate over dicts/objects/arrays using scriptblock with Param($k,$v)
function ForEach-KV {
    Param($var, $cb, $i=0)
    switch ($var.GetType().Name) {
        Array          { $var | % { $cb.Invoke($i++, $_) } }
        HashTable      { $var.Keys | % { $cb.Invoke($_, $var[$_]) } }
       "Dictionary``2" { $var.Keys | % { $cb.Invoke($_, $var.Item($_)) } }
        PSobject       { $var.GetIterator() | % { $cb.Invoke($_.Key, $_.Value) } }
        PSCustomObject { $var.GetIterator() | % { $cb.Invoke($_.Key, $_.Value) } }
        default        { $cb.Invoke($i++, $_) }
    }
}
```

Apart from that one irritating type name, there's a bit much duplication here. Which is why I was looking around for duck typing in Powershell.

For hashes and objects, it's easiest/obvious to probe for `.getIterator` or `.getEnumerator` (never couldn't quite remember which belongs to which anyway):

```
switch ($_) {
    { $_.GetEnumerator }  { do-loopy }
    { $_.GetIterator }    { do-otherloopy }
```

But now I'm not quite sure what to do about arrays here. There's not *that **one*** behaviour indicator in `[array]`s methods that really sticks out.

- `.Get()` does seem unique (at least not a method in HashTables or PSObjects), but sounds a bit *too generic* even for type guessing
- `.Add()` might as well be an integer method(?)
- `.GetUpperBound()` etc. come off as a bit too specific already.

So, is there a standard method that says "arrayish", preferrably something that's shared among other numerically-indexed value collections?

Comment: Never heard of duck typing until today. Really cool concept. What is the issue with `.GetUpperBound()` exactly? Are you trying to just match the array type specifically and not things that "implement" it?

Comment: @Matt No, indeed. I'm not really versed with .NET types. But if `.GetUpperBound` can be found in other array-style or listy types, then that might be a good qualifier after all. I'm really looking for "accidental compatiblity" with similar types. (Albeit I don't really need it in my case. Just was wondering, if/how feasible.)

Comment: Ah ok so you just want to be sure that it only identifies numerically-indexed `[array]` types and not false positives with non array types.

Comment: My question title is probably misleading. While yes, I mostly care about common arrays, the example would/should work with other list types. Looking at [.NET docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=netframework-4.7) types like Set/LinkedList/Stack would be similar (and presumably had an *implicit* index too). Right now this is more about discerning *value lists* from KeyValuePair stores.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match only arrays:

```
PS> $x = 1..10
PS> $x.GetType().IsArray
True
```

or you can check there is integer indexer:

```
(Get-Member -InputObject $x -Name 'Item' -MemberType 'ParameterizedProperty').Definition -match '\(int index\)'
```

Comment: The `.IsArray` is correct of course, but less what I'm looking for. (Though IDK, Powershell itself might condense some type guessing into there). - The introspection and signature check is interesting of course. Though just testing for a commonly-named method name is the goal. So is `.Item()` already specific to lists/arrays? (Hash and Object at least don't have it.)

Comment: If you have .NET object ParameterizedProperty means it is indexer. Anonymous indexer is generated as Item but you also need to check it is integer indexer. So it is a little tricky but I don't know better way.